# how to manage Read Capacity while Read to Amazon DynamoDB table?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Im looking for some advice In Dynamodb table design to create HashKey and SortKey

I have created table

```
HashKey - id     - date with some interval  
sortKey - mainId - date with timestamp
          userId  - someNumber
```

My simple code look like

```
ValueMap valueMap = new ValueMap();
valueMap.put(":pId", pId);
valueMap.put(":mainId", mainId);

StringBuilder userIdList =follwing userIds List;

QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec()
    .withProjectionExpression("id,mainId")
    .withKeyConditionExpression("id = :pId")
    .withFilterExpression("(userId in ("+userIdList+")))
    .withValueMap(valueMap).withScanIndexForward(false).withMaxResultSize(minSize);

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(querySpec);
```

Suppose I try to fetch data using id and filter by userId. In this case my all read capacity will be used as it read data by hash key and then it apply filter on it. So in this case after applying filter on the data, I didn't get any record.

So in this way above this ItemCollection return no records but it reads the all capacity (in case userId list not matched with fetched result)

how can I design table so read capacity not wasted, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

One option that you have is to add a `[Global Secondary Index][1]`. It allows you access data in a table as if you have to partition keys.

You can try either following table schema:

**HashKey**     - id     - date with some interval

**sortKey**     - mainId - date with timestamp

**GSI HashKey** - userId  - user id (allows to get a record by user id)

Or this one:

**HashKey**     - id     - date with some interval

**sortKey**     - mainId - date with timestamp

**GSI HashKey** - userId_id  - user id AND id in one attribute (allows to get a record that has both id and userId values)

To get multiple records you can use [BatchGetItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html):

> A single operation can retrieve up to 16 MB of data, which can contain
>   as many as 100 items. BatchGetItem will return a partial result if the
>   response size limit is exceeded, the table's provisioned throughput is
>   exceeded, or an internal processing failure occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I have "posts" like Instagram stored in table. So I want that in sorted order of time, and in bunch size of 10. It get those post of to whom I follow.

Comment: Do you want to get post order by time for a particular user?

Comment: Yes I want post order by time for not 1 particular user but for users to whom I follow. So here I have list of user_id with me, to whom I follow.

Comment: I think you would have to maintain a separate table with all posts visible for a user. A partition key would be a user Id and a sort key would be a timestamp. Then you would be able to get all posts that should be displayed to a user a sort them.